# In Visual Studio SSIS, can I specify a separate editor for Code and Design?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, editor

I'm using SSIS in Visual Studio, and by default the "View Code" option on a dstx file sends me to a really crappy XML editor that doesn't even have collapsability.  I installed Viasfora, hoping that that would improve it, but it didn't.  I have since realized that I just need to specify to use the XML editor, either in Open With... in Source Control Explorer, or in Tools/Options/Text Editor/File Extension.  However, in both those cases, not only does double-clicking on the file send me to the XML editor, but even RClick/View Designer in Solution Explorer uses the XML editor!  So, is it possible to have View Designer use one editor (like, the designer) and View Code another (the XML editor)?

Comment: Why not open the *.dtsx in Notepad++?

Comment: @JWeezy That's what I've been doing, but I'd like not to have to.  It is called an **Integrated** Development Environment, after all....

Comment: Well, you are able to view the XML, but not to your liking. Nobody said the IDE was perfect. lol. I gave up on VS20xx for XML viewing/editing and just use Notepad++. This might make it a bit easier: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CalvinAAllen.OpeninNotepad